# mysql distinct query based off non unique columns

Tags: mysql

I have a weird (probably bad table design) query question thatI cannot think of an easy way to  solve.

here is a table layout like what I have:

```
| id                 | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| num                | varchar(15) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| type               | varchar(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

type is actually,  enum("val1","val2","blah")

num can have 3 entries in the table,  one with each of the 3 different type.

The query I need is the count of distinct number of "num's" that have both an entry for "val1" and "val2".

I do not think there is a simple query to handle this.. but the only solution I have come up with is to dump distinct entries of val1 to a memory table,  distinct entries of val2 to a memory table.

Then determine which table has the least number of records.,  then write a subquery based off the smaller table looking for number matches in the larger table.

the above sounds like a bad hack though...

Am I missing something here...Do any of you see a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(*)
from `MyTable`
where `type` in ('val1', 'val2')
group by `num`
having count(distinct `type`) = 2
```

Comment: Thank's,  this almost works it gives me the correct output but i just need the count.  Either way you saved me from writing a stupid subroutine that obviously was not needed.

Comment: found another solution... I had no idea you could do a join on the same table...  select count(distinct a.num) from mytable as a join mytable as b on a.num = b.num where a.type = "val1" and b.type = "val2"

Comment: @trey85stang You *could* do a self join, but it is much slower, and you have to do a join for each value, so scales horribly. Imagine a list of 100 values...